# Insert ellipsis (…) into div tag, how to add functionality to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a modal dialog box with 7 columns. one of the column shows comment section. How can i restrict this section to 25 characters. I have used text over floe ellipsis, which shows ellipses after first word. I also want to add functionality to ellipsis such that on click of ellipses it should pop up a small window showing the whole section of the comment. how can i do it? can any body please help me with it?

this is the css i am using

@comment

Answer (score 0):

In CSS i can only see a trick with `pointer-events` and a pseudo elemet and a `tabindex` attribute in HTML.

```css
p {
  width:12.5em;/* 25 letters space average */
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  border:solid;
  pointer-events:none;
  position:relative;
  pointer-events:none;
}
p:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:1em;
  height:1.2em;
  right:0;/* lays over the ellipsis */
  top:0;
  pointer-events:auto;
  cursor:pointer;
}
p:focus, p:active {
  white-space:normal
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Browser then needs to understand pointer-events.